# Twitter API to listen to updates/new tweets from a user

Tags: javascript, twitter

Can you provide an example of twitter API to listen to a user's timeline?
This is what I currently have,

```
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name:  google, count: 1},
function (err, data, response) {
 if (!err) {
   console.log(data);
 }
});
```

I am currently able to do a GET call which gets the recent posts but I am looking to have a connection open to the stream that will get notified whenever a new tweet is posted on the user's timeline. Thanks.

Comment: can someone explain why this needs to be closed? and why downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Twitter's streaming APIs https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview

This is a non-javascript example http://mike.teczno.com/notes/streaming-data-from-twitter.html